# Timing of my code keeps showing it takes 0 seconds

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, time

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to time this program when it looks at 5, 10, 15, 20, etc for n but everything comes back with it taking 0 seconds. I'm using visual studio 2013.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
clock_t start_t, end_t, total_t;
int n, first = 0, second = 1, next, c;

printf("Enter the number of terms\n");
scanf_s("%d", &n);

start_t = clock();
printf("First %d terms of Fibonacci series are :-\n", n);

for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
{
    if (c <= 1)
        next = c;
    else
    {
        next = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = next;
    }
    printf("%d\n", next);
}
end_t = clock();
total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Total time taken by CPU: %f\n", total_t);
int  num;
scanf_s("%d", &num);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: The execution time is likely to be way less than one second. That is, `end_t - start_t` is going to be less than `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. And on many platforms (not sure about Windows) `clock_t` is an integer type. So assigning a double value between `0` and `1` to an int type will result in `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable total_t should be a double:

```
double total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Total time taken by CPU: %lf\n", total_t);
```

(Naming variables with the suffix _t is a really bad idea.)

Unless you calculation takes a significant amount of time, at least 10-16 milliseconds, clock() won't record any change due to its relatively high granularity.

Answer (score 0):

If your code takes a small amount of time relative to the granularity of the clock you have available, you can run it many times and then divide.

```
s = timer()
for ( times = 0; times < n; ++times) {
    dothing();
}
e = timer();
print (e-s)/n;
```

One thing you need to worry about is the optimizer being too clever and optimizing the loop away (if `dothing()` has no external side effects then there is no reason to do it at all, let alone thousands of times.  So have dothing return some value and print that value at the end.

```
x = 0
s = timer()
for ( times = 0; times < n; ++times) {
    x ^= dothing();
}
e = timer();
print (e-s)/n;
print x;
```

Answer (score 0):

after correcting the compile errors:

Always enable all warnings when compiling:

Always try to write portable code which may require this line at top of file:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement*.

in general, reserve the `_t` suffix for type declarations.

using a portable method of cleaning stdin, then waiting for user to press a keystroke

the following code is the result:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
    clock_t start;
    clock_t end;
    double total;

    int n;
    int first  = 0;
    int second = 1;
    int next;
    int c;

    printf("Enter the number of terms\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    start = clock();
    printf("First %d terms of Fibonacci series are :-\n", n);

    printf("%d\n", 0);
    printf("%d\n", 1);

    for (c = 2; c < n; c++)
    {
        next = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = next;

        printf("%d\n", next);
    }

    end = clock();

    total = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Total time taken by CPU: %f\n", total);

    int ch;
    while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

the following is a sample output:

```
Enter the number of terms
10
First 10 terms of Fibonacci series are :-
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
Total time taken by CPU: 0.000043
```